# Function to calculate sum of matrix gives error - [Error] array type has incomplete element type

Tags: c, arrays, types, element

Function to calculate sum of matrix gives following error - [Error] array type has incomplete element type

Could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code :

```
  #include<stdio.h>

  int some_tab(int t[][],int n,int m);
  int main(){

    int tab[100][100],i,j,n,m;

    printf("\ndonner le nombre de lignes : ");

    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\ndonner le nombre des columns : ");
    scanf("%d",&m);

    for(i=0 ; i<n  ;i++){  
      printf("\nLigne %d: \n",i+1);
      for(j=0 ; j<m ;j++){  
          printf("\n donner le nombre numero %d :  ",j+1);
          scanf("%d",&tab[i][j]);   

       }
     }      

    printf("\nla somme du tableau est %d :  ",some_tab(tab,n,m));

    return 0;
  }

  int some_tab(int t[][],int n,int m){

        int i,j,s=0;

        for(i=0;i<n;i++){  
            for(j=0;j<m;j++)                                 
                 s = s + t[i][j];                                 
         }
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: Changing the function to ```int some_tab(int **t,int n,int m)``` might fix.

Comment: @Punycode Be careful! Although a 1D array like `int arr[n]` 'decays' to a pointer like `int* p`, a 2D array like `int arr[n][m]` *does not* decay to an `int** pp` - it also decays to a single-level pointer (to `arr[0][0]`)!

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be like this :

```
int some_tab(int t[][100],int n,int m)
```

When passing 2-D array to function you need to mention column.
You can declare column globally like this :

```
#include <stdio.h> 
const int COL = 100;
...
```

**OR**
You can use pointer. Like this:

```
void some_tab(int *t, int m, int n){
   int i, j; 
      for (i = 0; i < m; i++) 
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) 
          printf("%d ", *((t+i*n) + j));
}
```

Comment: Your third example won't work unless `n` exactly matches the equivalent dimension specified in the calling routine! If not, the `i*n` "column offset" will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an array that has more than one dimension as an argument to a function, then only the ***first*** (leftmost) dimension can have an unknown size (empty `[]`). This is required because of the way the address of a given element is calculated.

For example, in this code:

```c
char array[10][20];
char b = array[3][2];
```

The variable `array` occupies a *contiguous* chunk of memory that is 200 (10 x 20) bytes in length. The address of element `array[0][0]` will be (obviously) the same as the array's base address. To get the address of `array[1][0]`, the compiler needs to add a value to that base address: in this case, that value will be the *size* of the second dimension (20); similarly, for `array[2][0]`, the address will be **two times** the size of the second dimension, and so forth.

When we then start changing the *second* index, we need only add that index's actual value to the calculated 'offset' for the first index. Thus, if we call the array's base address `ADDR` then, in the example above, `b` will be given the value of the `char` at `ADDR + 20 x 3 + 2`.

However, inside your `some_tab` function, the compiler doesn't know what the size of the second dimension of the `t` array is - so how can it calculate the appropriate address offset to use for the element `t[i][j]`? (Note that the compiler can cope with not knowing the size of first dimension, because that size is never used in calculating the address of an element!)

To get round this, in your case, the *simplest* (though not necessarily the *best*) way is to give the second dimension a *fixed size* that is: (a) big enough to handle all cases the code will have to deal with; and (b) used ***100% consistently*** throughout your code. So, you could use this:

```c
int some_tab(int t[][100], int n, int m);

int main {
    int tab[100][100], i, j, n, m;
    //..
    printf("\nla somme du tableau est %d :  ", some_tab(tab, n, m));
```

However, the following will fail horribly because it breaks point (b), above:

```c
int some_tab(int t[][200], int n, int m); // Change 100 to 200 for bigger space?

int main {
    int tab[100][100], i, j, n, m; /// This is now WRONG because tab has different 2nd dimension size!
    //..
    printf("\nla somme du tableau est %d :  ", some_tab(tab, n, m));
```

*Note: I have used a `char` array here to keep the explanation brief, as the `char` type has a size of *exactly* 1 byte. For other types, the calculated offset for any element would simply be multiplied by the size of that type.*

EDIT: When I first posted, I couldn't test the (better) code that follows, as I was 'restricted' to using the MSVC native `C` compiler (which uses a very old language standard that prohibits it). However, now that I have been able to test with `clang`, I can confirm that the following code compiles and works as expected.

What this does is to use **known** but ***variable*** dimensions for an array, which are passed to the `some_tab` function at run-time (the compiler can still calculate each element's offset correctly but, rather than using a *fixed* multiplier for the second dimension, it uses a *variable* (in this case, the value of the argument `m`).

Make sure to read the comments I have added, marked with the triple-slash (///):

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int some_tab(int n, int m, int t[n][m]); /// We MUST pass the "n" and "m" arguments FIRST!
int main()
{
    int i, j, n, m; /// NOTE: Declaration of "tab" MUST be moved ...
    printf("\ndonner le nombre de lignes : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\ndonner le nombre des columns : ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    int tab[n][m]; /// ... to AFTER we know the actual values of "n" and "m"!!
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("\nLigne %d: \n", i + 1);
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("\n donner le nombre numero %d :  ", j + 1);
            scanf("%d", &tab[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\nla somme du tableau est %d :  ", some_tab(n, m, tab)); /// Change argument order!
    return 0;
}

int some_tab(int n, int m, int t[n][m])  /// Note that this matches the pre-declaration!
{
    int i, j, s = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            s = s + t[i][j];
    }
    return s;
}
```

Please feel free to ask for any further clarification and/or explanation.