# Counting negative numbers in each column in an 2d array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to count the negative numbers in each column of a square matrix (2D array), and I'm doing it on two arrays. My problem is that my program seems to read rows, not columns, and the results it gives for the first array is incorrect, even though the second array's results are fine.

This is the code I have:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int Z[20][20], int z)
{
    int i, j;
    int count[10];

    for (i = 0; i < z; i++)
    {
        count[i] = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < z; j++)
        {
            if(Z[i][j] < 0)
            {
                count[i]++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < z; i++)
    {
        printf("\n Col %d = %d", i, count[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int A[10][10], B[15][20];
    int i, j, n = 3;

    printf("\n Table A: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n Table B: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
            scanf("%d ",&B[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",B[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    function(A,n);
    function(B,n);
    return 0;
}
```

My matrices are:

```
A:             B:
 3 -4 -5        3 -5  2
-2  1  3       -3 -1  6
 5 -7 -4        8 -5  4
```

And this is the output I get:

```
 Table A:
3
-4
-5
-2
1
3
5
-7
-4

 Table B: 3
-5
2
-3
-1
6
8
-5
4
3
3 -4 -5
-2 1 3
5 -7 -4

3 -5 2
-3 -1 6
8 -5 4

 Col 0 = 2
 Col 1 = 2
 Col 2 = 0
 Col 0 = 1
 Col 1 = 2
 Col 2 = 1
```

Comment: Your code is atrociously formatted. Please reformat it consistently, and so you only have one statement per line.

Comment: Your `function` expects a 20x20 array, but you are passing it a 10x10 array and a 15x20 array. The compiler probably output some warnings about incompatible pointer types.

Comment: OK, so maybe I'm "blowing my own trumpet" here, but an answer I gave a few days ago may help you understand why you need to be ***consistent*** with your array dimensions, between `main` and `function`; see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216754/10871073

Comment: `void function(int Z[20][20], int z)`, `int A[10][10]` and `function(A,n);` is troubling code.  Enable all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to count the negative numbers in each column of a square matrix (2D array) and I'm doing it on two arrays.

Here is the first problem, because one of the arrays showed in the posted snippet isn't *square*:

```
int A[10][10], B[15][20];
//               ^^  ^^
```

They also have different numbers of columns (one 10, the other 20), but the function `function` is declared as

```
void function(int Z[20][20], int z)
{ //                    ^^       ^  Expects an int [][20] and a number of columns
    int i, j;
    int count[10];
    //        ^^   Only 10, while you pass a matrix with 15 columns
    for (i = 0; i < z; i++)
    {
        count[i] = 0;
        //    ^          Out of bounds if i >= 10
// ...
```

You can fix it by changing the function signature and using a Variable Length Array to store the values

```
void function(size_t rows, size_t cols, int Z[rows][cols])
{ //                 ^^^^         ^^^^        ^^^^  ^^^^
    size_t count[cols];
    //           ^^^^
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cols; ++i)
        count[i] = 0;   // This is a job for memset, though

    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
        {
            if( Z[i][j] < 0 )
            { //  ^  ^
                ++count[j];
                //      ^
            }
        }
    }
// ...
```

Note, though, that this task doesn't require an array to store the sums. You could print those value as soon as they are calculated, you just need to traverse the arrays in column-major order:

```
void function(size_t rows, size_t cols, int Z[rows][cols])
{
    for (size_t col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
    { 
        size_t count = 0;
        for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
        {
            if( Z[row][col] < 0 )
            { 
                ++count;
            }
        }
        printf("Col %zu = %zu\n", col, count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to find count of negative numbers in each column. But in your function you are counting the negative numbers in each row (not column). You can verify this by counting the negative numbers and matching it with output of your program. You can fix it by simply changing the index in your function like -

```
void function(int Z[20][20], int z) {
    int i,j;
    int count[10];
    for (i=0; i<z; i++) {
        count[i]=0;
        for(j=0; j<z; j++) {
            if (Z[j][i]<0)
                count[i]++;
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<z; i++) {
        printf("\n Col %d = %d",i,count[i]);
    }
}
```

Notice the change in if condition from `if (Z[i][j]<0)` to `if (Z[j][i]<0)`. That way when say `i` is 0 in inner loop you are accessing `Z[0][0]`, `Z[1][0]` and `Z[2][0]` giving you the numbers in column 0. Same for column 1 and 2.

In your question you have mentioned that your code gave right answer for second array. But if you look closely, it is giving wrong value for column 1 and 2.

Also, change your code according to the advises everyone else has given.

Answer (score 0):

**[EDITED]**

I think you have a problem with `int count[10];`, I assume you are assuming all your arrays are 20 long, so you're declaring it 10 long, and in c you can do it but you'll write in memory which you do not own.

Try something like:

```
void function(int inputArray[20][20], int arrayLength) {
    int i,j;
    int count[arrayLength];
    for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
        count[i] = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < arrayLength; j++){
            if(inputArray[i][j] < 0){
                count[i]++; 
            }
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
        printf("\n Col %d = %d", i, count[i]);
    } 
}
```

Also try to write ordered code, which is easier to read and debug.

Comment: _you'll write in some other variable which you don't know_ might better be stated _you'll write in memory which you do not own_

Comment: I've arranged the code but the problem still persists. I've used `count[10]` as a limit for the arrays. Also it shows me warning like this `passing argument 1 of 'function' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]`